# Get Particular value from result string

Tags: php

What I received XML response is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response status="200">
   <invoice_id>829584</invoice_id>
</response>
```

I want "invoice_id" from above data. So anyone please help for the same. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it with:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
           <response status="200">
               <invoice_id>829584</invoice_id>
           </response>';
$xmldom = simplexml_load_string($xml);

echo $xmldom->invoice_id->__toString();
```

for more detail have a look at [Php simple load xml](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

Comment: I want the value of status. can you help ?

Comment: try `$xmldom->attributes()->status->__toString()`